# If one forgot that they already said a bracha and then said it again does it count as a bracha levatala?

Tags: blessing

A person was eating dates and said borei pri hoaytz before starting, ate a few dates, said borei pri hoaytz again and then continued to eat.

Does the second borei pri hoaytz count as a bracha levatala?

Comment: AFAIK this is a beracha sh’eina tzricha, because, while unnecessary, it is indeed chal (meaning that it takes effect), unlike a beracha levatala which does not and is therefore completely in vain.